# Negative and positive numbers golang

Tags: go, integer, numbers, negative-number

I can't figure out how to build the code correctly. Please help me dumb(

Here is the task itself

Write a program that uses the number entered to determine which of the four stacks it should be placed in. The program asks the user for a number and displays a message:

1. The number is negative and even if the number is less than zero and is an even number

2. The number is negative and odd if the number is less than zero and is an odd number

3. a number is positive and even if the number is greater than zero and is an even number

4. A number is positive and odd if the number is greater than zero and is an odd number

I tried if and else

Also I don't understand if it is possible to execute with - switch?

It's already a headache. The only thing I can do is to define integers and non integers. I don't understand what to add to the code to define negative and positive numbers.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var score int
    fmt.Scanln(&score)
    if score%2 == 0 && score < 0 {
        fmt.Println("The number is negative and even")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The number is negative and not even")
    }
}
```

Why when entering a positive number, the program still writes that the number is negative

Because I specify that a<0

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will classify all numbers you input as 'negative' because there is no print statement in your program that prints the word 'positive'.

You can use a different, but still rather simple approach to tackle this problem:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var score int
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&score)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // print whether the number is negative, zero, or positive, and also whether it is even or odd, in one line
    // take note that fmt.Print is used here and not Println, so that it does not append a newline to the end of the string
    if score < 0 {
        fmt.Print("The number is negative")
    } else if score == 0 {
        fmt.Print("The number is zero")
    } else {
        fmt.Print("The number is positive")
    }

    if score%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Println(" and even")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(" and odd")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding

I'm just starting to learn the GO language.

The only thing I haven't gotten past the interface yet is "nil" and "panic"
And it's still unexplored for me.

The problem is that I'm solving a problem on the passed material, and there are no more words except for if and else. There is also switch
And I need to solve the problem after the passed material(

Is there a solution without nill and panic?

Comment: @ Brandon Li

Anyway, thank you very much

Maybe I'll be able to pass all the assignments in time and be able to enroll for free tuition)

Comment: Oh, it is totally possible to do forgo the panic statement, as well as nil. Simply replace ```_, err := fmt.Scanln(&score)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }``` with just `fmt.Scanln(&score)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You've been a great help!